# How to show that $\{(a,a) : a \in A\}$ is a null set of $A \times A$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. How do i show that $\{(a,b) : a,b \in A \text{ and } a=b\}$ is a null set of $A\times A$?

It is easy to see for intervals but the general case I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B=\{(a,a)\mid a\in A\}$, then
$$
\mathbf{1}_B(x,y)=1\iff \mathbf{1}_A(x)\mathbf{1}_{\{x\}}(y)=1
$$
and hence
$$
\begin{align}
\lambda_2(B)&=\int_{A\times A} \mathbf{1}_A(x)\mathbf{1}_{\{x\}}(y)\,\lambda_2(\mathrm dx,\mathrm dy)=\int_A \mathbf{1}_A(x)\left[\int_A\mathbf{1}_{\{x\}}(y)\,\lambda(\mathrm dy)\right]\lambda(\mathrm dx)\\
&=\int_A\mathbf{1}_A(x)\lambda(\{x\})\,\lambda(\mathrm dx)=0,
\end{align}
$$
where we have used Tonelli's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is open, then the complement of your "diagonal" is open end dense in $A\times A$.